# Setting strtotime adding a variable to amount of days

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to export a certain number of days and setting it to the variable $max_future. Currently it is a set amount of days but I want the users input variable to be the number it has instead.

Currently it is set as:

```
$max_future = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today . "+6 days"));
```

I want something like:

```
$exportDays = '9'; //(or whatever the user input was)
$max_future = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today . "+$exportDays days"));
```

Is this possible? I appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried it before posting question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$max_future = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today . "+" . $exportDays . " days"));
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I should have thought of doing this... still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
<?php
$output = 9; // you can take this value from input.
$today = date("Y-m-d");
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' +'.$output. ' days'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $exportDays = $_REQUEST['exportDays']; // or however you want to get it from user input
    $max_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' +' . $exportDays . ' days'));
```